# React Native 0.71 Android Offline JS Bundling

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to optimize my React Native application for CI.  One thing I did for iOS is build the JS bundle and iOS app in parallel and then inject the JS bundle later and resign.  I realized that I can't quite do that for Android but I would like to see if I could build the JS bundle separately and then use it as part of a release build for Android.  Has anyone done this before? It seems that the react native CLI gives the ability to build an offline JS bundle but doesn't say how it can be used.